# Recommendation for handling RoR App with Subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, subdomain

I'm currently evaluating options for adding sub-domain support to a new Ruby on Rails app and was wondering if there were any suggestions or experience that others could share.

Some possible Choices

SubDomain-Fu

http://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu/tree/master

Rolling your own

http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2009/01/11/subdomain-accounts-with-ruby-on-rails-explained

DHH Style
http://37signals.com/svn/posts/1512-how-to-do-basecamp-style-subdomains-in-rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend [subdomain-fu](http://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu/tree/master). I did a [Railscasts episode on it](http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains) a while back and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I can add all the subdomains in my /etc/hosts file but can do it dynamically with * wildcard. Am I missing something.

Comment: I use a proxy.pac file to redirect *.local urls. Ryan's railscast mentions it as well.